# I need to configure an RSA TFA client

Tags: authentication

I am looking for instructions on how to set up a Ubuntu 16.04.5.6 device to require RSA TFA for authentication. This would be for both Desktop and SSH.

Thank you

Comment: Did you even look for any?   A simple startpage search provided (second entry) a howto for Ubuntu 16.04 RSA MFA (using google-authenticator as it's example) for ssh.  There is no Ubuntu 16.04.5.6  (it's *yy.mm.point-release* format so you'll be on 16.04.5 or 16.04.6; if on .5 you need to upgrade)

Comment: I did see that one (Google Auth) for SSH in my early hunts. But that is not RSA. I need to be able to connect this to our ACE / Radius server for authentication.  Most of the items that I have found for RSA TFA are RedHat only, Those packages are configured for RedHat.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my inquiry.